# Get MIDI pitch-bend range in Python

Tags: python, midi

In MIDI, the pitch-bend range is `2` per default, but [can be modified via specific RPN messages, usually followed by specific "Data Entry" messages](http://midi.teragonaudio.com/tech/midispec/rpn.htm).

Python MIDI file parsers such as `pretty_midi` and `mido` seem to ignore these MIDI messages.

How do I correctly read the pitch (including non-default pitch-bend range)?

Comment: pretty_midi gives you raw control change events, and does not recognize pitch bend range when handling pitch, so it does not work for files with custom pitch bend ranges. mido does not handle pitch (it just reports it), so you have to interpret it yourself anyway.