# MIDI pitch-band range

Tags: audio, midi

As far as I understand, the pitch-bend range in MIDI can be changed only in the following ways:

- Option 1: B**0**6500 B**0**6400 B**0**06**02** B**0**26**04**

  The "**0**" after the "B" is the MIDI channel for which the pitch-bend range is being set.

  The "**02**" in the end of the third message is the number of semitones by which the pitch can bend.

  The "**04**" in the end of the fourth message is the number of [cents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_(music)) to be added to the semitones.
- Option 2: B**0**6500 B**0**6400 B**0**06**02**

  i.e. same as Option 1 but the fourth MIDI message is optional.

Edit: As per @aMike's comments:

- Option: Leave out `B0` in any (?) except the first message as per the "running status" specification.

Is this correct, and are there no other ways, i.e. can't the second MIDI message be left out? Where are all options listed and explained?

Comment: These are RPNs: Registered Parameter Numbers. The first two messages set the hi/lo parts of the RPN number, the second two messages set the fine/coarse parts of the value. See document here https://www.recordingblogs.com/wiki/midi-registered-parameter-number-rpn and here http://midi.teragonaudio.com/tech/midispec/rpn.htm   and question/discussion here:  https://discuss.cakewalk.com/index.php?/topic/13873-confused-about-pitch-bend-values-vs-rpn-pitch-bend-sens/

Comment: @aMike Are there only the two options I listed, and no other options for setting the pitch-bend range? (I mean standard MIDI files rather than vendor-specific constructs.)

Comment: @root What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: @Brad Expecting as an answer? For example "yes" or "no", accompanied by a quote from the MIDI specification that says that these are the only two options or that lists additional options to set the pitch-bend range.

Comment: @root I don't think there are other back doors to set the PB range. It's not two options - it's one RPN.  It looks like there are 6 official RPNs, according to that recording-blog article. Similar discussion here: http://www.somascape.org/midi/tech/spec.html#rpns

Comment: Oh, yeah, you can use running status to leave out the *B0* after the first one.  To quote from the spec - I can't get to the MIDI spec because I don't want to register for it on their site. Silly of me, I know.

Comment: @root Let me ask you this way... what problem are you trying to solve, specifically?

Comment: @Brad I'm trying to get the correct pitch from MIDI files. Seems like a basic task, but I can't find any software [in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75965872/) nor [in JavaScript](https://github.com/nfroidure/midifile/issues/33) that can do that correctly. Pitch depends on pitch-bend range, pitch bend, channel fine tuning, channel coarse tuning. In turn, each of these values can be set in one or in several ways (for example, I listed two options in the question, and aMike listed two more in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76740748/?noredirect=1#comment135320028_76740748)).

Comment: @aMike Thanks, that's the kind of stuff I've been looking for. I don't want to register, either. Maybe this link helps: https://web.archive.org/web/20151205005352/http://www.midi.org/techspecs/index.php